# Searching by encrypted column in DynamoDB

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, amazon-kms

I have a DynamoDB table which as per requirement should have only serialNumber and created by .serialNumber  should be encrypted . how can I search based on this column . since user would
pass the actual serialNumber and I have to validate it against db .

how can I achieve the same ?

the encryption algo generates a different value on encryption .

I even tried using scan , but not able to search based on serial number value .

```
response = dynamodb.scan(TableName='table')
    items = response['Items']
    for item in items:
        response = client.decrypt(
        CiphertextBlob=item['serialNumber'],
        KeyId='keyId',
        EncryptionAlgorithm='SYMMETRIC_DEFAULT'
    )
```

I get following error when trying to decrypt :

```
[ERROR] TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: did you get the answer here? have same problem with Java code

Comment: its not possible with the approach . you need a unique identifier. to do that you can also  use one way hashing to the data to get information from the table. if you need more inputs let me know.